# Can we differentiate complex functions as if they were real?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am taking a first course on complex analysis and I am wondering whether we can differentiate complex functions as if they were real.

Most of the functions I have come across i.e. $\cos z, \sin z, \cosh z$ etc. follow the same rules of derivation as their real counterparts.

Are there certain conditions that allow me to make this assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the differentiation formulas for analytic functions are the same as their real versions.  That is, if $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions on some domain $D$ whose intersection $D \cap \mathbb R$ with the real line contains an interval, and 
$f'(x) = g(x)$ for $x \in D \cap \mathbb R$, then by analytic continuation
$f'(z) = g(z)$ for all $z \in D$.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have a function only containing $z$ and not something like $f(u+iv)=u^2+iv^2$, you can apply all rules that work in the reals.

Answer (score 0):

Complex functions that can be differentiated as if $z$ is real must satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations. That way they are said to be complex differentiable.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDifferentiable.html